# What's the proper distribution for the following data

Tags: python, normal-distribution

I have the following sample data.
It looks like right half of the normal distribution.

Suppose the data is `read` time of a blog article.
What I want to do is to find out how each blog article is performing in terms of `read` time.

With regular normal-looking distribution, I'd find `mean` and `std` of a populartion, then given a sample(a blog), find the mean `read` time of the blog and compute p-value of the sample mean.

But since the distribution is not like-normal.. what should I do?

Below is the data.

```
tds_ = [28.965,
 12.172,
 17.042,
 36.98,
 20.323,
 3.481,
 18.43,
 5.638,
 20.763,
 48.104,
 8.015,
 21.2,
 48.122,
 32.51,
 16.87,
 10.402,
 7.896,
 3.827,
 0.078,
 18.63,
 42.428,
 0.975,
 11.392,
 15.937,
 4.531,
 44.635,
 10.457,
 53.821,
 43.046,
 39.572,
 6.31,
 52.039,
 36.726,
 19.67,
 43.719,
 9.421,
 2.798,
 20.013,
 32.888,
 43.622,
 13.093,
 38.688,
 57.199,
 13.627,
 42.571,
 34.076,
 18.812,
 49.251,
 57.412,
 35.089,
 8.093,
 15.141,
 58.05,
 17.936,
 4.673,
 5.475,
 11.731,
 46.649,
 12.403,
 6.442,
 22.542,
 44.069,
 7.893,
 26.484,
 4.199,
 6.575,
 3.209,
 32.125,
 40.202,
 37.918,
 27.567,
 22.634,
 43.355,
 44.481,
 17.854,
 29.538,
 2.39,
 16.52,
 34.321,
 8.003,
 28.034,
 20.963,
 16.509,
 26.279,
 13.541,
 22.654,
 32.074,
 9.474,
 1.054,
 11.612,
 2.108,
 19.015,
 0.864,
 7.577,
 9.927,
 7.295,
 6.689,
 13.908,
 2.063,
 31.57]
```

Here I'm showing distribution and the normal ..
(From a sample, I create a negative copy of it and append to the sample)
Then it looks like the normal distribution

[image]

```
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

tds_half = pd.Series(tds_)
tds_inverse = tds_half * -1

tds = np.append(tds_half, tds_inverse)

mean = np.mean(tds)
std = np.std(tds)


mean, var, skew, kurt = norm(mean, std).stats(moments='mvsk')
x = np.linspace(norm(mean, std).ppf(0.01),
                norm(mean, std).ppf(0.99), 100)
ax.plot(x, norm(mean, std).pdf(x),
        'r-', lw=5, alpha=0.6, label='norm pdf')



rv = norm(mean, std)
ax.plot(x, rv.pdf(x), 'k-', lw=2, label='frozen pdf')

vals = norm.ppf([0.001, 0.5, 0.999])
np.allclose([0.001, 0.5, 0.999], norm.cdf(vals))

r = tds

ax.hist(r, density=True, histtype='stepfilled', alpha=0.2)
ax.legend(loc='best', frameon=False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: ... this is not really a programming question, is it? (asking for a program that finds the distribution of some data is possible, but is somewhat a huge task. Mathematica has [FindDistribution](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindDistribution.html))

Comment: (by the way, as you've already figured out, apparently there's something called [Half-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution). But it could be geometric or something-else too)

Comment: well, I guess you are right on it being not programming question, but apparently there's a program `mathematica` that helps me here hah! @user202729

Answer (score 0):

I generate a random selection to create a normal distribution of 10,000 samples.  Next I plot the histogram and the probability distribution function using the mean and standard deviation of the data.

```
tds = [28.965, 12.172, 17.042, 36.98, 20.323, 3.481, 18.43, 5.638,20.763, 48.104, 8.015, 21.2, 48.122, 32.51, 16.87, 
    10.402, 7.896, 3.827, 0.078, 18.63, 42.428, 0.975, 11.392, 15.937, 4.531, 44.635, 10.457, 53.821, 43.046, 39.572,
    6.31, 52.039, 36.726, 19.67, 43.719, 9.421, 2.798, 20.013, 32.888, 43.622, 13.093, 38.688, 57.199, 13.627, 42.571,
    34.076, 18.812, 49.251, 57.412, 35.089, 8.093, 15.141, 58.05, 17.936, 4.673, 5.475, 11.731, 46.649, 12.403, 6.442,
    22.542, 44.069, 7.893, 26.484, 4.199, 6.575, 3.209, 32.125, 40.202, 37.918, 27.567, 22.634, 43.355, 44.481, 17.854,
    29.538, 2.39, 16.52, 34.321, 8.003, 28.034, 20.963, 16.509, 26.279, 13.541, 22.654, 32.074, 9.474, 1.054, 11.612,
    2.108, 19.015, 0.864, 7.577, 9.927, 7.295, 6.689, 13.908, 2.063, 31.57]

 mean=np.mean(tds)
 std=np.std(tds)
 N=10000

 fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))
 results=norm.rvs(mean,std, size=N)
 ax.hist(results,bins=100)
 twin_ax=ax.twinx()
 x = np.linspace(norm(mean, std).ppf(0.01),
            norm(mean, std).ppf(0.99), N)
 twin_ax.plot(x, norm(mean, std).pdf(x),   'r-', lw=5, alpha=0.6, label='norm pdf')
 plt.legend()
 plt.show()
```

you should test to see if the data is a normal distribution.

normal distribution:

1. 68% is within 1 standard deviation
2. 95% is within 2 standard deviations
3. 99.7% is within 3 standard deviations